# Trying to update parameters in ASP

Tags: asp.net, parameters, html-select

I get this error:'DropDownList2' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

What does this mean? I have DropDownList2 bound to the correct value, but I keep getting this error.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doctor" SortExpression="Doctor">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdDoctorList" DataTextField="Doctor" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Doctor") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>




 <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OHIP" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitsPerYear" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DoctorID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Timestamp" Type="Byte"></asp:Parameter>
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: its means what is says, your database have a value that is not on the dropdownlist box.

Comment: but it does... I'm using the same SQLsource on a dropdownlist outside of this template and it works fine. Same source different textbox...